# Search does not link to the correct location for local Android SDK documentation

Tags: android

After updating the Android SDK and corresponding documentation on my Mac the search results for the locally stored documentation stopped linking to the correct locations. The search results link to root ("/") instead of the local documentation directory (ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY/docs/).

"Documentation for Android SDK" is for API version 16 and is revision 1.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I edited one of the documentation Javascript files.
The edited function is search_changed (about line 174) in the file ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY/docs/assets/js/search_autocomplete.js. Added the following to the start of the function:

```
var cur_loc = window.location.pathname;
var slash_doc_slash = cur_loc.indexOf("/docs/");
if ( slash_doc_slash >= 0) {
    var after_bit = cur_loc.substr(slash_doc_slash + "/docs/".length);
    var after_bit_length = after_bit.length;
    var up_dots = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < after_bit_length; i++) {
        var test_ch = after_bit.charAt(i);
        if ( test_ch == "/") {
            up_dots += "../";
        }
    }

    toroot = up_dots;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the js file `ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY/docs/assets/js/search_autocomplete.js`, it appears to me that the search result is draw by google web search api. If we want to modify the search result, we have to rewrite the search engine part of the codes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the search box just feeds the query to Google's servers, which reply with URLs on https://developer.android.com.   For searching and opening pages on the local SDK, I use this shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z $SDK_BASE ]; then
    SDK_BASE=/opt/android-sdk
fi

launched_new_window="false"

for f in `find $SDK_BASE/docs/ -iname \*$1\*.html`; do
    if [ $launched_new_window = "false" ]; then
        /usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window $f
        launched_new_window=true
    else
        /usr/bin/chromium-browser $f
    fi
done
```